# ArcMap frequency table of field values that are above a certain value in another field

Tags: arcmap, frequency

I am using ArcMap 10.5. I have a table of species list length from visits to sites over a period of years. I have a column for site, giving the grid reference of each site, and a column giving the number of species recorded on that visit. I want to create a frequency table that tells me how many visits where 2 or more species were recorded were made to each site.

Essentially I want to run the 'Frequency' tool on the 'site' field, but only calculate frequency for the rows where the 'species' field is >= 2.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried select by attributes rows with >=2 species then run frequency tool.

Comment: Embarrassed not to have thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select by attribues rows >=2 species then run frequency tool. Only selected rows will be included.